# How to apply quantization to vertex coordinates?

Tags: mesh, meshlab

Question title is pretty self explanatory.

I couldn't find any option to quantize vertex coordinates. 
I think Meshlab determines itself but I want to determine it myself. (32bit 16bit 10bit etc.)

Does meshlab capable of quantization of vertices? If not what is the default bit value of vertex representations?

Answer (score 1):

To my acknowledge, meshlab is not capable of doing that. I suggest you to export your mesh in ply ascii file format and use matlab or python to process the lines of the coordinates.

Comment: thanks for your reply. however meshlab is a complete program which includes lots of features, There are really complex algorithms it implements. Quantization is so simple that it needs to be in the feature list default in my opinion.